# OpenLayers 3 view.setRotation shortest rotation change direction

Tags: openlayers, heading

I am experimenting with OpenLayers 3 for the first time and am looking to follow the user's position and heading.

I'm following their heading with

```
deviceOrientation.on('change:heading', function(event) {

    var heading = event.target.getHeading();
    view.setRotation(-heading);
});
```

This seems to work reasonably well but every few seconds the view will do almost 360 degree spin when only moving slightly. I believe this is because the setRotation is going "the long way round" to the new heading value. Is there a way to ensure it rotates the direction which involves the shortest movement to the new heading?